# What does "werewith" mean in this context?

Tags: archaicisms, research

> > “You may remember the inquiries I made, when you *werewith* me in England, among such of my relations as were then living; and the journey undertook for that purpose.”
>
> — Quoted in Benjamin Franklin, Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin with his Essays and Will (Chicago: W.B. Conkey Company, 1900).
>
> *Emphasis via italics is by me and not from the original text*

---

**Research**:--

**References and Sources**:--

- (http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/were%20with)

**Other References and Sources**:--

- ([https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=40&q="werewith"&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=40&q=%22werewith%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5))
- (https://www.quora.com/What-does-werewith-mean/answer/Robert-Charles-Lee)

Comment: It should be “were with”—a typo in whatever version you have.

Comment: Other places ([example](https://books.google.com/books?id=y_tdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq="You+may+remember+the+inquiries+I+made")) that quote have the correct spacing "... when you were with me.."

Comment: The issue is that there is the archaic  term "were with"/"werewith", then there is the term, "were with" which is simply the modern use of the term and is sometimes misspelled as "werewith."

Can someone please correct me if I am mistaken? This is what is confusing me. I am not very sure about what I just wrote.

Comment: I think "were-with" (archaic) and "were with" (modern use of the term) are different terms. I am absolutely not sure, so I am checking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "werewith" is merely a typo, as others have pointed out.

---

By `archaic term "werewith"` you mention, are you by any chance referring to some other word such as [*wherewith*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wherewith)? It is an archaic word, too.

Comment: I just found this:

(https://www.quora.com/What-does-werewith-mean/answer/Robert-Charles-Lee)

Comment: Well, I think he got confused by the typo as well, since "when you *accompanying/escorting* me in England" lacks a verb, not really making sense.

Comment: Maybe? :) He did say it was a real word, later on. :D

Comment: He did, but he did not present any support other than the *same* quoted piece of text containing the word that is suspected to be a mere typo, as already shown by Laurel.

Comment: The only thing I could find that confirmed what he said was this:

(http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/were%20with)

Comment: That does **not** validate it. Note that the phrase consists of *two words*, not one.

Comment: I'm checking the text, Dictionary of obsolete and provincial English : containing words from the English writers previous to the nineteenth century which are no longer in use, or are not used in the same sense. And words which are now used only in the provincial dialects,

Comment: @TautologicalRevelations The OED Online (the huge, historical dictionary, not the much-smaller Oxford Dictionaries Online) doesn't have "werewith"; it doesn't appear anywhere in the entire text of the dictionary. It does, of course, have "wherewith" as suggested here, and also "herewith", so I can see why one might suspect the existence of "werewith"...but it really is just a typo. (The random, sourceless Quora guy is wrong.)

Comment: His credentials are verifiable: (https://hk.linkedin.com/in/robert-charles-lee-4361b970)

Comment: To put the "not in the OED even once, anywhere" in context, "herewith" has its own entry *and* appears in five definitions, 3 etymologies, and 101 quotations. Altogether it appears somewhere in the full entry of 95 different words. The even-more-obscure "herewithal" appears in three different entries. "Were" on its own appears in ***66646*** different entries.

Comment: I found this, but it could merely be another instance of what you described: 

“...among which sounding our trumpets and other instruments of musicke, both of  still and loud noise; werewith he was so much delighted, that requesting our musick to come unto the boate, hee joyned his Canow to the same and was towed at least a whole houre together, with the boate at the sterne of our ship.”

MLA Citation: "Drake, Francis. The world encompassed. No. 16. B. Franklin, 1854."

Comment: I found this:--

(https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=werewith&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwerewith%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I've decided to not make an issue out of this, and simply drop this matter. Best wishes.